# Break between div groups

Tags: html, responsive

I am trying to make a break between divs for responsive viewport. here is my code and what it looks like now. I am new to css and html. I need 4 divs to be in one row and the rest of 4 divs in the second row but they should stack up to 2 divs per row in small and extra small viewports.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">24 Hr Access</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Unlimited Coffee</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Mail Service</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-archive  fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Vintage Design</p><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;"> Insanely Fast Internet</p><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">HD Projectors</p><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-building-o fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Conference Rooms</p><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Group Events</p><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is css:

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.benefitItem{
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is how it looks now
[image]

I want it to look like this 4 divs in one row
the rest 4 dives in the second row

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a

```
<div class="row">
```

at the very top of the code that you posted, just left off of the copy and paste.

1) The easiest To make the row of 8 items stack into 2 rows of 4 items each (in the medium, large, and extra large viewports) would be to add another  after the 4th item. This looks like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">24 Hr Access</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Unlimited Coffee</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Mail Service</p>
        </div>
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-archive  fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">Vintage Design</p><br/>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="benefitItem">
                <i class="fa fa-wifi fa-lg"></i><br/>
                <p style="overflow-wrap: break-word;"> Insanely Fast Internet</p><br/>
        </div> ... (continued)
```

2) To make the two rows break into 4 rows of 2 items in the small and extra small viewports, you need to add a flex-wrap: wrap; line to your .row css class AND create a media query for the smaller viewports with:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .benefitItem {
    flex-basis: 50%;
  }
}
```

You can change the 640px value to be the breakpoint at which you want the 2-item stacking to start.

I'm not sure this is the MOST efficient way to solve your problem, but it worked for me!